# Visual Assist low performance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-assist

I am using Visual Assist X for C/C++ code in Visual Studio 2005 but I see that, sometime, when visual studio take focus, the processor is working too much and I cannot type code. If I am waiting somes seconds, it return the focus.

Answer (score 4):

You should really try asking on the [Visual Assist forum](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/default.asp) if you haven't already.  They have great support there.

They may have solutions/workarounds for the problem, and if not they probably want to know about the problem so they can fix it.

Comment: +1, and to assist future browsers of this question, here is the exact thread specifying how to move the VAX databases to a faster drive. http://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=6865

Answer (score 3):

Try 'Rebuild' of the Symbol databases and a 'Clear' of the History, cache and temporary files from the 'Performance' tab of the Visual Assist X Options dialog. You can also turn other 'optimizations' off here that may be causing performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to speed up parsing times significantly by modifying settings from the `VAssistX` menu:

```
    VAssistX | Visual Assist X Options... | Projects | C/C++ Directories
    VAssistX | Visual Assist X Options... | Projects | Extensions
```

This will allow you to flag certain directories as stable which means they won't be repeatedly re-parsed.  Adding VC++ header directories (e.g., `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include`) and large libraries, such as Boost, to this list should help.

As other have mentioned, the [Visual Assist X forums](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/default.asp) are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs with large files and/or large number of open files and is due to parsing of those files.

This is a known problem on the [Visual Assist forum](http://www.wholetomato.com/forum/default.asp).